# Trigger to update record when Value = GETDATE()

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, getdate

my experience with triggers is that it does something after an update,insert or delete. But is it possible to create a trigger to update a record automatically when its date is today? for example, I have a table with 4 columns.

```
   StartDate         EndDate         Active          Expired 
---------------------------------------------------------------
   2013-01-03      2013-01-05          True           False
```

this is one record, what i want is to create a trigger that will update the `Active` column to `False` and `Expired` to `True` of this record when its `EndDate` is = today's date (GETDATE()). How do i do this?

Comment: This sounds like a daily job - see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx) for an example.

Comment: I guess that's what i have to learn now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as far as I know, you can't use a trigger for this situation.
Triggers are executed, when data/records change.
In your case, the data is not changing, only time is passing.

Look for a 'SQL job' to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

To make your columns `Active` and `Expired` to behave the way you want, you shoould make them computed columns. The sql for those columns would be this (assuming they are `DATE` columns):

```
--For column Active
CASE WHEN EndDate < CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

--For Column Expired
CASE WHEN EndDate >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

well in your case you have 2 options:

create a view (converting `getdate()` to 112 to remove time):

```
create view <your view name>
as
    select
        T.StartDate,
        T.EndDate,
        case when T.EndDate <= convert(nvarchar(8), getdate(), 112) then 1 else 0 end as Active,
        case when T.EndDate <= convert(nvarchar(8), getdate(), 112) then 1 else 0 end as Expired
    from <your table> as T
```

And then you can select data from your view (BTW, I don't think you need both columns, because they depends on each other)

Or you can create a SQL Job to check if Date is equals today and update your columns.